# Flex Wrap Elements So They Are Still Justified to the Center - CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using `flex-wrap` on a bottom nav element. Is it possible to center the wrapped element (which by default is then aligned to the left after it wraps)?

In the example below the menu-items wrap to left hand side when the window size is reduced.

Many thanks for any help.

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/PoYZJxO).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.pipe {
    margin: 0 .5rem 0 .35rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="bottom-nav">
    <li class="tl bottom-nav-items link">Lorem Ipsum<span class="pipe"> | </span></li>
    <li class="tl bottom-nav-items link">Lorem Ipsum<span class="pipe"> | </span></li>
    <li class="tl bottom-nav-items link">Lorem Ipsum<span class="pipe"> | </span></li>
    <li class="tl bottom-nav-items link">Lorem Ipsum<span class="pipe"> | </span></li>
    <li class="tl bottom-nav-items link">Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: When you are using flex property you can use ```justify-content: center;``` but when your wrapped element comes down and it will create a center align effect without filling the left space... As you can see in your example last li element is center aligned but not starting from where all other li elements are starting. For that you can use ```justify-content: flex-start;``` and then set you flex div to fix width and use ```margin: 0 auto;``` to center the entire div. This will not cause your last li element to be center and the whole div will be still center aligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `justify-content:center;` The content gets centered without going to left 
Hope this is what you are looking for

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content:center;
}

.pipe {
    margin: 0 .5rem 0 .35rem;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="bottom-nav">
  <li class="tl bottom-nav-items link">Lorem Ipsum<span class="pipe"> | </span></li>
  <li class="tl bottom-nav-items link">Lorem Ipsum<span class="pipe"> | </span></li>
  <li class="tl bottom-nav-items link">Lorem Ipsum<span class="pipe"> | </span></li>
  <li class="tl bottom-nav-items link">Lorem Ipsum<span class="pipe"> | </span></li>
  <li class="tl bottom-nav-items link">Lorem Ipsum</li>
</ul>
```